# Durandal's activator

Tags: javascript, durandal

I've stumbled on issue related to `Activator Lifecycle Callback` in **Durandal**.

Here is my model with a bunch of callbacks.

```
define(function () {
    return {
        activate: activate,
        viewAttached: viewAttached,
        detached: detached,
        deactivate: deactivate,
        title: 'Lifecycle'
    };

    function activate() {
        debugger;
    }
    function viewAttached() {
        debugger;
    }
    function detached() {
        debugger;
    }
    function deactivate() {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

But ***detached*** and ***deactivated*** methods are not raised.

According to documentation these callbacks run when an activator is present. So the question is how can I add an activator module to my model?

**UPDATED:** composition of the model looks like:

```
<!-- ko compose: { model: 'lifecycle', activate: true } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: If you are speaking about durandal 2.x, then according documentation this callbacks run when activator is **not** present. Here is the link to docs http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.htm , see "Key Points" at the top of page: `Activator callbacks are not executed unless an activator is present.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Durandal are you using?

If you are using Durandal 1.x, the 'detached' method does not exist. It was added in version 2.0. Also, the 'viewAttached' method was changed to 'attached' in version 2.0.

Regardless of version, you are spelling the 'deactivate' method incorrectly. There is no 'd' on the end.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! I'm using version 1.2. So I've corrected the typos but still have no success with triggering of the 'deactivate' method. Maybe I have to mention this model is used as partial. 

<!-- ko compose: { model: 'lifecycle', activate: true } -->
<!-- /ko -->
As you can see I use 'activate: true'. Could it be that this method is affecting somehow lifecycle events?

Comment: Ahh! Yes, that makes a difference. There are two different life-cycles in Durandal, Composition and Activator. Since you are using container-less composition of this view, Durandal will use its Composition Life-cycle. In this life-cycle, there is no 'deactivate' hook. Read up on it [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a the Durandal 1.2 knockout samples at https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/samples/knockout/index.js for an example how to manually use an `activator`.

```
define(function () {
    var system = require('durandal/system'),
        viewModel = require('durandal/viewModel');

    return {
        activeSample:viewModel.activator(),
        introSamples: [{
            name: 'Hello World',
            hash: '#/knockout-samples/helloWorld',
            moduleId: 'samples/knockout/helloWorld/index'
        }, 
        ...
        ],
        activate: function (args) {
            var that = this;

            if (!args.name) {
                args.name = 'helloWorld';
            }

            return system.acquire('samples/knockout/' + args.name + '/index').then(function(sample) {
                that.activeSample(sample);
            });
        }
```

`router` implements an activator by default, so all event life cycle events are available. By using `activate: true` only the subset of events is enabled.

Durandal's 1.2 documentation is not available online since the 2.0 release, but it's still available as download from http://durandaljs.com/pages/downloads/. Here's the relevant part from `Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html` that explains that scenario.

> 1. The Router has an internal activator called "activeItem" which manages the current page.
> 2. You can create an activator yourself at any time by requiring the view model module and calling it's *activator* function. This returns
>      a computed observable that serves as the activator for your objects.
> 3. When you call `app.setRoot` an activator is used on your root module.
> 4. If you set `activate:true` on a *compose* binding, an activator will be used during composition.
>
> **Note:** Cases 3 and 4 are a bit different as they only enforce *canActivate* and *activate* callbacks; not the deactivation lifecycle.
>   To enable that, you must use a full activator yourself (cases 1 or 2).